# Facebook Registration Plugin And Friends List

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook registration plugin and wanted to see if its possible to get list of users friends after user submits a form loggin in facebook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make a graph api call to `/me/friends` with the `access_token` you are given in the `signed_request`.